# Row selection when dragging over a UITableView with scrolling disabled

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, interface-builder

If one were to create a standard grouped table view consisting of two rows and then touch down on the first row, the cell would highlight. If one were to then drag one's finger down, the selection of the row cancels, and the table view begins to move with the drag.

Imagine the same situation, but with table view scrolling disabled via `tableView.scrollEnabled = NO`. Now, when one has selected a row and begins to drag, the row deselects and the table remains static.

I have two questions:

1. How can I ensure the row isn't deselected when one selects and drags within the confines of the row?
2. When one drags from the first row to the second row, how can I ensure that the first row is deselected and the second row becomes selected?

For an example of this functionality in action, open the Clock app and select the Alarm tab bar item. Tap the top right plus button and a modal view will appear presenting four rows. Tap down on the first row, drag onto the second, and you'll see the selection move across rows while the table itself remains static. How is this achieved?

Comment: Woah. I've just noticed how many times I used the indefinite personal pronoun 'one' in this question... I promise I wasn't trying to sound clever; it just kinda came out that way.

Comment: In the Clock app, the table view does have scrolling enabled.

Comment: @lemnar: It seems a recent OS update has changed the way this works. :¬( I'll have to try to find another example somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

On a tableView with scrollEnabled = NO when you touch on any cell you get a didHighlightRowAtIndexPath, and when you start to drag you get didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath (even if you stay within the cell). The cell is not selected or deselected when you drag, and no further cells highlight/unhighlight on that touch.

There is a shouldHighlighRowAtIndexPath method that is called, where you can decide if the touch should highlight the row or not, but not a shouldUnhighlight method.

If the 'flash' of the highlight/unhighlight bothers you, you could use the shouldHighlight method to just return NO. Or you could return NO if a cell is selected.